# Configure DNS for SharePoint 2013 app store

Tags: sharepoint-addin

To configure the SharePoint app store in an intranet environment, do I need to buy a domain with a supplier, or just need to configure an internal DNS server in my new domain zone?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to buy a domain. Just ask your IT admin to configure it internally. Have a look at this article : [Setup app environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)